# How to deal with relations between classes in object oriented languages?

Tags: java, class, oop, kotlin

I'm trying to model a situation using Java/Kotlin(any OOP language really). I've to make a task management app.

## Requirements

- There should be a `Task` class and a `Tag` class
- A `Task` can have multiple `Tag`s and a `Tag` can have multiple `Task`s associated with it
- Each `Task` can have multiple sub-tasks. Each sub-task is a `Task` itself

---

I'm using a relational database with the following 4 tables:

- Tasks
- Tags
- TasksAndTags(relates Tasks and Tags)
- TasksAndSubTasks(relates Tasks with Tasks to represent sub-tasks)

---

The database schema is pretty straight forward but I'm having trouble choosing the best option in my application code.

I've 3 options. If you prefer GitHub gists, see [this](https://gist.github.com/AnEnigmaticBug/ee2f0213f32a5e699142d239258efad2) link. It has highlighted code.

---

## Option-1

```
data class Tag (val id: Long, val name: String, val icon: Int)
data class Task(val id: Long, val name: String, val tags: List<Tag>, val subTasks: List<Task>)
```

### Pros

- The design is more 'object-oriented' and intuitive

### Cons

- It is really difficult to use with a relational db. Cycles complicate this even more
- I'm forced to load all the sub-tasks every time I load a task even if I don't access the sub-tasks field at all
- The above problem is worsened because each of those sub-tasks may have their own sub-tasks

---

## Option-2

```
data class Tag (val id: Long, val name: String, val icon: Int)
data class Task(val id: Long, val name: String, val tags: List<Tag>, val subTasks: List<Long>)
```

### Pros

- Since we only store ids, we've to load less data
- No issues due to cycles

### Cons

- Using ids feels like dealing with relational model rather than object oriented model

---

## Option-3

```
data class Tag (val id: Long, val name: String, val icon: Int)
data class Task(val id: Long, val name: String, val tags: List<Tag>)
```

### Pros

- The structure matches that of entities/tables in our db(minimized mapping code)
- Each individual object is small

### Cons

- We've to use other methods of accessing sub-tasks. For eg: by having methods of the form `getSubTasksForTask(task)`
- The `Task` class itself tells us nothing about the existence of the concept of sub-tasks

---

**Question1**: This problem is arising because of relations between objects. I believe this situation is really common and there must be a good way to deal with it. Please let me know which option is preferred and how to minimize it's cons.

**Question2**: In all the options, I've made the `Task`s hold their tags but not the `Tag`s hold their `Task`s. While this may be intuitive(not necessarily correct) to me, what's the best way to deal with such relations?

EDIT: I'm on Android. So, lazy loading is out of bounds for me :(

Comment: The first one. You can use lazy loading to eliminate the performance issue.

Comment: @Michael I'm on Android. So, lazy loading is not feasible for me :(

Comment: `I believe this situation is really common and there must be a good way to deal with it.`, yes, use an Object Database.

Comment: @PeterMmm I can explore Object databases but given the widespread usage of relational databases, I would like a solution which works with them

Comment: Why you can not use `lazy loading`?

Comment: @NightMare "I believe this situation is really common and there must be a good way to deal with it". Yes it is and yes there is. You have to start by making up your mind whether you want to use (a) a relational schema in an RDBMS or (b) an object-oriented "persistence" store. Relational databases are so called because they store facts that are connected by semantic relationships. (i.e. by the meaning of the facts) In contrast, OO "objects" are connected to each other by messages that use non-semantic object ID's (aka "oids"). They are different paradigms that can't be mixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a straight froward design and not ideal at all but show the concept

[Gist here](https://gist.github.com/ksviety/bf7acccebb5a0708bf377f72b2af39fc)

First you extract types

```kotlin
interface Named {
    
    /**
     * Returns the name of this object
     */
    fun accessName(): String
}

interface Task : Named {

    /**
     * Returns the tags this task has
     */
    fun accessTags(): Iterable<Tag>
    
    /**
     * Returns the sub-tasks that belong to this task
     */
    fun accessSubTasks(): Iterable<Task>
}

interface Tag : Named {
    
    /**
     * Returns the icons id of this tag
     */
    fun accessIcon(): Int
}
```

Then you implement concrete classes like this

```kotlin
class DatabaseTag(private val id: Long) : Tag {
    
    override fun accessName(): String {
        TODO("Load the name from database and return it")
    }
    
    override fun accessIcon(): Int {
        TODO("Load the icon from database and return it")
    }
}
```

This makes the architecture flexible and allows you to use different data source while the code still uses the same `Tag` type, you only pass different implementations.

Also if you want to make it work faster you can add a decorator that will for example cache the values that are loaded from the database first time and only load it once, then return the cached value

```kotlin
class CachedTag(origin: Tag) : Tag {
    private val name by lazy { origin.accessName() }
    private val icon by lazy { origin.accessIcon() }
    
    override fun accessName(): String {
        return name
    }
    
    override fun accessIcon(): Int {
        return icon
    }
}
```

Then you can replace the `DatabaseTag` with a `RestTag` and still use the `CachedTag` to wrap it and only load once